# average Joe vs. ordinary Joe vs. everyday normal guy vs. regular guy

Tags: word-choice, american-english, phrase-choice

I'd like to write something like the following sentence.

Original sentence:
**Like a regular guy, you don't like picking up your dirty socks.**

Or maybe this sentence is not a wise word choice because a regular guy seems to be a positive thing.

Unfortunately, I'm stuck. I have no idea which one is the best choice.

## Average Joe, ordinary Joe

[average Joe --> urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=average%20Joe)

[average Joe, ordinary Joe --> wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_Joe)

[average Joe --> a title of tv series](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0380850/)

## Everyday normal guy

[everyday normal guy --> youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5PsnxDQvQpw)

[everyday normal guy 2 --> youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GmG4X9PGOXs)

## Regular guy

[regular guy --> urbandictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=regular%20guy)

[regular guy --> a title of a book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0679772715)

I have a few questions:

1. Which of these terms are neutral ones?
2. Are "average Joe" or "ordinary Joe" old-fashioned? Do people use them in 2018?
3. Which one is the best choice for my sentence?

My summary:
The word choice depends on a person who says such a sentence.

1) a regular guy
Man who assumes it's normal to do such things

**Like a *regular* guy, you don't like picking up your dirty socks.**

2) a typical guy
Woman who criticizes the man's behavior:

**Like a *typical* guy, you don't like picking up your dirty socks.**

3) Who would say such a sentence?

**Like an *ordinary* guy, you don't like picking up your dirty socks.**

Comment: @Codewife_101 I have deleted my answer as it seems like I may have misunderstood your intent.  I'd suggest cleaning up or deleting/replacing your question so it's clear what you want to know.  You ask which word is best in your context, but we can't tell whether you want to say that most men are indecent or not.

Comment: @farnsy Too bad! I think your answer was very useful. It was a good explanation of these tricky terms, even though it didn't exactly answer my question. I'd be grateful if you could undo your action. There are a lot of useful comment out there.

Comment: @J.R. Where are all these comments? Did you edit (delete)  them as well? I'm a little bit concerned about that. From an English learner's perspective, there were very helpful. At least, I learned that "typical" is used in most cases as a pejorative adjective, but there is no trace of that because comments were deleted too. I'd appreciate if you could bring them back.

Comment: I have deleted no comments on this question.